# Input helpers and accessibility for visually impaired

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm writing a specific kind of North American phone number input helper that displays a box next to the input, dynamically displaying the formatted outcome of the partially entered result. If the user has so far typed "2345678" into the input, for instance, the box will show "(234) 567-8___".

If the user then types an "@", the box will show "(234) 567-8@__" in red to indicate an invalid character, or if the user then types "012", the box will show "(234) 567-8012" in green to indicate a valid, complete entry.

Does anyone have a sense of whether it would be helpful to try to make this give feedback for screen reader users as well? Perhaps, by giving the input helper box an aria-live=polite attribute value? ... or would that just be annoying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to surface the error to someone using a screen reader, you'll need to add error text to a different node on the page that has an `aria-live` attribute, and [hide it accessibly](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/) if you choose.

Note that `aria-live='polite'` will wait for the current read order to finish. If you want the user to stop and adjust his or her action right away, an `assertive` value is more appropriate.

As an alternative, use client side validation and raise the error on submission. Consider using [`<input type='tel' />`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html) to do this. This would be more standard and less disruptive solution.

In either case, announce the expected format in a way that is associated with the input, either beforehand or as part of an error message.

Comment: The helper is already a separate element that is being used to advise sighted users, so I was thinking to simply add the aria-live attribute to that. My understanding is that 'polite' would start speaking as soon as the user paused during typing, which seems appropriate rather than trying to speak after every keypress. Using input type of 'tel' is a good thing, but on its own, does nothing with regard to formatting. The pattern attribute will validate, but not automatically fill in parentheses, etc. or give feedback about the eventual reformatted value/validity.

Comment: Ah -- I see what you mean about the separate element. That's for the error or completion reporting, which should interrupt.

Comment: I guess my question is less about how to do it and more about whether doing it is a good thing. Since I find it useful as a sighted user, I'm guessing that a blind user would find it useful too, but I don't know. Perhaps, this would be annoying in excess of its value?

Comment: In my opinion, audibly announcing typos/formatting changes for a blind user is disruptive and annoying. It is more interruptive than a visual highlight would be for a sighted user, even if it waits for typing to finish. I suspect if you announce required format and do client side validation, it'd be more in line with expected behavior for blind users.